# Em quais casos a tag <ins> é usada?

Tags: html, html5

Umas das tags de formatação HTML é a tag `<ins>`, mas tudo que achei sobre ela é que serve para marcar um texto inserido. Eu quero saber mais detalhes de que texto *"inserido"* é esse, e em quais casos essa tag é usada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag `<ins>` é útil quando um texto que foi inserido na página foi modificado.

Frequentemente, a tag `<ins>` é utilizada com a tag `<del>`, que representa que um determinado texto não é mais válido.

Um bom exemplo seria a data para a realização de uma prova, e caso a data fosse alterada, ao invés de apagar a data antiga e inserir a data nova, aplicamos a tag `<del>` na data antiga e `<ins>` na data nova, mantendo um histórico de alterações na página e chamando a atenção do usuário final para a alteração que foi feita.

Answer (score -3):

A tag  é normalmente usada para marcar um intervalo de texto que foi adicionado ao documento.

O texto inserido é renderizado como texto sublinhado pelos navegadores da web, embora essa propriedade possa ser alterada usando a propriedade CSS text-decoration. A tag  requer uma tag inicial e final.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).